# ExtJS combobox set initial value dynamically from remote store on page load via PHP

Tags: php, extjs, combobox

My current issue relates to showing an initial value in an ExtJS combobox relating to an employee's department in an employee detail page.

The page retrieves the employee information via PHP, so all the references to the employee are done through PHP echo (the site uses CodeIgniter, which may confuse some; it just simplifies some of the input but works in the same way as normal PHP), i.e.

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'User Details',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.get('details'),
    store: userStore,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items:
    [
        {
            fieldLabel:'User Name',
            name: 'UserName',
            allowBlank: false,
            value: '<?php echo $Employee->UserName; ?>'
        },
        //More details in similar format etc.
    ]
});
```

There is a section for the departments, to be handled through a combobox, to list all departments; there is nothing fancy (I believe), it just lists all the departments:

```
    Ext.define('DeptModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name:'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name:'Name', type: 'string'}
        ]
    });

    var deptStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model:'DeptModel',
        autoload: true,
        proxy: {
            // load using HTTP
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?= $site_url ?>Settings/JSON/Departments',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                model: 'DeptModel'
            }
        }
    });
```

The formPanel above then references the deptModel/deptStore in a comboBox:

```
{
    fieldLabel:'Department',
    xtype:'combo',
    name:'Department',
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    emptyText: 'Choose a Department',
    store: deptStore,
    displayField: 'Name',
    valueField: 'Id'
}
```

The above combobox renders correctly and provides all the departments.  Attempts to initialise the combobox with a value, however, have not worked, ranging from no change in the combobox to creating errors that stop the page rendering. I have looked at the following:

```
value: 5   // or any integer
value: '5' // or any string
value: <?php echo $Employee->DepartmentId ?> // or any PHP reference like those that work for the textfields e.g. the User Name above - DepartmentId has been checked to be an integer
value: '<?php echo $Employee->DepartmentId ?>' // stringifying the PHP reference
value: 'Accounts'
```

I have also looked at the numerous posts relating to loading stores after rendering, setting values on store loading, setting values on render, setting values before the formPanel code; quite frankly, none have worked, and most refer to setting the value to the first in the list which doesn't treat my particular issue.

Ideally, I want to simply state

```
value: <?php echo $Employee->DepartmentId ?>
```

to have the combobox display the relevant department (i.e. "Accounts") when the employee's details are displayed in the form on page load.

Where am I going wrong? Why does `value: {value}` not do anything in practice? Can anyone provide a simple explanation as to the correct form of inserting a combobox into a formPanel that allows for the initial value in said combobox to be picked on page load, if the current implementation is somehow incorrect?

Comment: Chances are, the store hasn't loaded the data before you try to set the value. You will have to wait to set the value until after the store has loaded.

Comment: I'd appreciate some guidance on the code needed to correctly set the value, or correctly load the store so that the value can be set and correctly displayed. I've tried to understand the various listings in the documentation for both stores and comboboxes, but I'm not seeing where best to load the store (or how given the available commands and the current setup) or set the value at the correct time - referring to my code would help for my understanding of the best place for any new code.

Comment: So, does your store load the data correctly? If you remove the line that sets the value initially, does the store load correctly and no errors occur? If so, then you will need to use an event, such as the store's `load` event, to fire off some code that sets the value of the combobox. Basically, you need to make sure the data is loaded before setting the value.

Comment: When "value" isn't being set, the store loads correctly and no errors occur. I have noticed, though, that the store doesn't seem to load until I interact with the combobox; hence my trying to understand when and where to load the store on page load, and when and where to set the value just after the store is loaded - but my understanding is very limited, and the documentation doesn't provide a suitable example! I've been able to set the value with a local store (see comment in below conversation with Oğuz Çelikdemir), but the departments must be retrieved from a remote store.

Comment: @DavidSmithson could you please check my last attempt?

Comment: Well, if `autoLoad` is set to true in your store, then it should load on page load. I took a second look at your store definition, and you have `autoload: true`, but it should be `autoLoad: true`. (uppercase L) Change that and verify that your store is loading automatically. Then you should be able to set the value after the `load` event fires (by adding a listener to the store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JsonStore:**

```
var articleMain = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
model: 'ArticleMainGroup',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard/create',
    extraParams: {
        type: 'article_group_main'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'articleMainGroup',
        idProperty: 'ART_GROUP_ID'
    }
}
});
```

**Data Model :**

```
Ext.define('ArticleMainGroup', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'ART_GROUP_ID', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'WHG', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'WHG_BEZ', type: 'string'}
]
});
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function create()
{
    $type = $this->input->get('type', TRUE);

    // this parameter comes from ExtJS Extraparam
    switch ($type)
    {
        case 'dnr_type':
            $data = $this->dnr->get_dnr_type();
            exit(json_encode($data));
        case 'dnr_definition':
            $para = $this->input->get('dnrtype', TRUE);
            $data = $this->dnr->get_dnr_definition($para);
            exit(json_encode($data));
        case 'article_group_main':
            $data = $this->dnr->get_article_group_main();
            exit(json_encode($data));
```

**Model:**

```
    public function get_article_group_main()
    {
        $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT ART_GROUP_ID, WHG, CONCAT_WS(" - ", WHG, WHG_BEZ) AS WHG_BEZ FROM MD_ARTICLE_GROUP GROUP BY WHG_BEZ ORDER BY WHG');
        return array('articleMainGroup' => $sql->result_array());
    }
```

**Here is your request :**

```
{
  fieldLabel:'Department',
  xtype:'combo',
  name:'Department',
  forceSelection: true,
  typeAhead: true,
  allowBlank: false,
  emptyText: 'Choose a Department',
  store: deptStore,
  displayField: 'Name',
  valueField: 'Id',
  id: 'cmb-department'
}

// Add a listener to the combobox before store load
var combo = Ext.getCmp('cmb-department');
var cmbStore = combo.store;
cmbStore.on('load', function() {
   // setValue(777) // here, 777 is unique value that available in the store
   combo.setValue(<?php echo $Employee->DepartmentId ?>)
})
```

Comment: Thank you: I made some minor alterations ("setValue" became "combo.setValue", and explicitly loaded the store after the function), but the code sets the initial value correctly. For those in a similar situation, I've only used the code from "Add a listener to the combobox before store load" onwards, but I can appreciate that the jsonStore code works using the backend code to retrieve the desired initial value; had I been coding this from scratch I would have probably used the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you but you should correct some mistakes. For instance, you had created data model like below :

```
    Ext.define('DeptModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: 'json'
    },
    fields: [
        {name:'Id', type: 'int'},
        {name:'Name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

But, data model should be :

```
Ext.define('DeptModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
        ...
    ]
});
```

So, you should define proxy properties in store config, not data model! The reason is that stores interact with server side, data model just modeling the data.

```
var deptStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'DeptModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Settings/JSON/Departments',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'deptList',
            idProperty: 'DEP_ID'
        }
    }
});
```

Here, I defined a simple store. You must take notice that `root` and `idProperty` properties. You should give a name of the Json object like below :

```
// return value from model
$sql = $this->db->query('SELECT DEP_ID, ......');
return array('deptList' => $sql->result_array());

// return value from controller
$data = $this->db->get_dept_list($arg);
echo json_encode('$data');
```

Also, `idProperty` is important which it should be unique value to be able to eliminate value conflict.

Here is the sample screen shot of my app. As you can see, when an user select a value from `DNR TİPİ`, app automatically populate the `ÌNDİRİM TİPİNİ SEÇİNİZ` combobox!

[image]

On the screen shot, `discDetail` equal your `deptList`.

Comment: I've removed the proxy code from the model; mostly an oversight on my part, and the true proxy code is in the store anyway.  Your method of using a JsonStore isn't something I'm familiar with; does this solve the stated problem of setting the combobox value to the employee's department on page load, given all the information is already available in the existing code?

Comment: David, I gave you part of my code which is working properly. As I said, you had mistaken on some settings.

Comment: check screen shot David!

Comment: I understand about the removal of the proxy data from the model, and followed your advice. However, changing the existing, working store and backend code to do the same function does not resolve correctly loading the store in the combobox, or correctly setting the combobox's initial value. Are you saying use of the JsonStore is best practice? You aren't providing an explanation as to how changing the store will help with correctly loading the store and setting the combobox value, which I would think all of which are coded outside the store definition.

Comment: I've just seen the screenshot, and I think there may be some confusion. I'm not trying to update comboboxes when other combobox values are being set. There is only one combobox involved, and this needs to have its value set on page load; no user interaction with the combobox should be required unless the value is being changed by the user. I thought this would be through setting the value attribute of the combobox, but this doesn't appear to work, and wish to know when and how to set this value when the page loads.

Comment: As an aside, I have managed to - in a separate "status combobox" governing active/blocked status - have the initial value being set on page load referencing a PHP value; this is however using a local store embedded within the "status combobox", rather than a remote store. What I need to know for the "department combobox" is the right place(s) and method(s) to load the store and set the value.

Comment: `There is only one combobox involved, and this needs to have its value set on page load;` it's so simple. You should add `autoLoad` property in the JsonStore config!

Comment: `autoLoad` simply tells the store to load it's data when it is created. It doesn't help with the issue of waiting for the data to be loaded before setting the value of the combobox.